# Jssor Slide animation scrolling the page

Tags: animation, slide, jssor

How to make animation Jssor Slider when scrolling the page.
Which is implemented by means of: animate.css, WOW.js.

Example - [http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)/

Thank U.

Answer (score 0):

The api $Play and $Pause enable you toggle auto play of jssor slider. Please detect page scroll and toggle auto play then.